# Error when allocating a two dimentional array of an Object in C++

Tags: c++

I am building a class called ParticleMatrix that stores a two dimensional array of the object Ball. I want to dynamically allocate space for them. The code looks like this.

```
/* 
 * allocateParticle takes a width w, height h, restlength RL then allocates space for
 * and constructs a 2D array of Particles of subclass Ball. 
 */ 
void ParticleMatrix::allocParticles(int w, int h, float RL)
{
    // Gets the number of particles in the xDirection
    xPart = getNrPart(w,RL);
    // Gets the number of particles in the yDirection
    yPart = getNrPart(h,RL);

    // Allocates a row of pointers to pointers.
    ballArray = new Ball*[xPart];
    // The ID of the particles.
    int ID = 0;

    // For every particle in the xDirection
    for(int x = 0; x<xPart; x++)
    {
        // Allocate a row of Ball-pointers yPart long.
        ballArray[x] = new Ball[yPart];

        // For every allocated space
        for(int y = 0; y<yPart; y++)
        {
            // Construct a Ball
            ballArray[x][y] = Ball( ID, RL*(float)x, RL*(float)y);
            ID++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs with the line "ballArray[x] = new Ball[yPart]". CodeBlocks gives me the compiler error " error: no matching function for call to 'Ball::Ball()' ".
I have 4 constructors for Ball with different signatures, none looking like: "Ball()".

I have tried with adding a constructor "Ball::Ball()" and it compiles then but I feel like I should be able to just allocate space for an object and later instantiate them.

What I'm wondering is: Why can't I allocate space for the object Ball without having a constructor "Ball::Ball()" in the code above?
and: If it is possible in some way to allocate space without the constructor "Ball::Ball()", how would I go about doing it?

I know I can create the constructor "Ball::Ball()" and give the objects some dummy values then later set them to their required values, but I feel uncomfortable doing this since I don't know why I couldn't just "Allocate space -> instantiate object". I hope I was able to explain my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `new T`, that gets memory and calls ctor, you can call `operator new` with a size you supply. The only provides you memory and nothing else. Then you can call `placement new` on properly calculated locations, that will invoke only your ctor. On the location you posted instead of allocating anew.   Search google for the provided terms to see examples.

But normally you're not supposed to do any of that, your task can be done well using a `std::vector<Ball>` with way less effort and more security.

Comment: Thank you Balog Pal. I will read up on that. I have thought about using std::vector but since this project is just for me to experiment and learn C++ I want to get familiar with manual memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Another "C++ way" of doing this is using [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

It provides you `allocate` and `deallocate` which only reserve memory without constructing elements.

```
  std::allocator<Ball*> ball_ptr_allocator;
  std::allocator<Ball> ball_allocator;

  Ball ** ptr = ball_ptr_allocator.allocate(10);

  for (size_t x=0; x<10; ++x)
  {
    ptr[x] = ball_allocator.allocate(10);
    for (size_t y=0; y<10; ++y)
    {
      ball_allocator.construct(&ptr[x][y], ID, RL*(float)x, RL*(float)y);
      // if you do not have access to C++11 use this:
      // ball_allocator.construct(&ptr[x][y], Ball(ID, RL*(float)x, RL*(float)y));
      ++ID;
    }
```

---

Note several issues here:

- I'd generally suggest to use unsigned types for sizes (like size_t for example).
- If you make the allocator a member you can access is in the destructor etc. to deallocate stuff again. `std::allocator<Ball> m_ballAlloc;`
- You have to (somehow) keep track of the constructed elements and allocated memory. If one of the constructions will throw an exception you should be able to clean up the constructed elements and deallocate the allocated memory.

For the deallocation tracking you can go with an additional loop in your allocParticles

```
for(size_t x = 0; x<xPart; x++) ballArray[x] = nullptr;
```

Now you know that every `ballArray[i]` that is not a nullptr needs to be deallocated.

But you'll have to destroy your elements first.
If you make your ID a member variable of the class you can use it to destroy constructed elements (since it's only incremented after element construction).

I wrote a destructor example with respect to ballArray destruction only, note that you'll may have to take care of other resources, too, if present.

```
~ParticleMatrix (void)
{
    // check this here and set ballArray to nullptr upon construction
    // of the ParticleMatrix
    if (ballArray != nullptr)
    {
        // start to destroy the Balls
        size_t destroycounter(0U);
        for(size_t x = 0; x<xPart; x++)
        {
            for(size_t y = 0; y<yPart; y++)
            {
                if (destroycounter < ID) 
                {
                    m_ballAlloc.destroy(&ballArray[x][y]);
                    ++destroycounter;
                }
            }
        }
        // deallocate 2nd dimension arrays
        for(size_t x = 0; x<xPart; x++) 
        {
            if (ballArray[x] != nullptr) m_ballAlloc.deallocate(ballArray[x], yPart);
        }
        // deallocate first dimension
        delete [] ballArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pixelchemist. I did not know about allocate and deallocate. I will read up on them.

Comment: @Massa Thanks but you hopefully didn't refer to its shortness, since thats unfortunatelly passé. But i felt like pointing out several additional issues. ;)

Comment: No, I **really** appreciated the C++-ness of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the operator `new` does not just allocate space for a variable, but also **constructs** it. If you don't have a default construtor `Ball::Ball()`, then you cannot construct each object in the array. There is no "just allocate space" in C++, *in principle*...